# How to Use Google Data API in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-data-api

In my c# project, I am using Google Data API SDK to connect to my Gmail account.  In order to get connect to my Gmail account, I use QueryAuthenticationToken() method.  But it shows warning that the name is not absolute, instead use QueryClientLoginToken().  I have also tried QueryClientLoginToken(), but it is showing error again.  So, please help me to solve this problem!

### Code

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Service Srv;
  Srv = new Service("Gmail Login Service", "Gmail Login");
  Srv.setUserCredentials(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

  String result;
  result = Srv.QueryAuthenticationToken();

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.","Message");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success","Message");

}
```

When I try to execute the above code, I get the following Error

### Error Message:

Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

Then I Modify the above code as follows:

### Modified Code:

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Service Srv;
  Srv = new Service("Gmail Login Service", "Gmail Login");
  Srv.setUserCredentials(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

  String result;
  result = Srv.QueryClientLoginToken();

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.","Message");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success","Message");

}
```

But I again show me the following error.

### Error Message:

Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA0qI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tsie.png)

Comment: Please include the code as text within the question, and then the full exception details, again as text. It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Http 404 error means Not Found

Comment: The Google Data APIs do not work with gmail. The [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) is separate and newer.